# Scala type system, cannot find common ancestor inline

Tags: scala, scala-cats, mockito-scala

I am on an heavily typed system with some generic methods declared as `def execute]C <: A#C](cmd: C):EitherT[Future, Fail, Seq[A#E]]` (where `A`  is a generic type on the class.

This works well. However in my tests, when I mock those calls, I have to explictiely type the super types of `Fail` and `A#E` or my code cannot compile.

```
// Event is the base type of Receiver#E
val event:Event = SubOfEvent()
handler.execute(any[SubOfCommand]) returns Seq(event).asRightT[Future, Fail]

val fail:Fail = SubOfFail()
handler.execute(any[SubOfCommand]) returns fail.asLeftT[Future, Seq[Receiver#E]]
```

If I inline the declarations of `event` or `fail` I have a *Type mismatch*:

```
  found   : cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,SubOfFail,scala.collection.immutable.Seq[SubOfEvent]]
  required: cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,Fail,scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Receiver#E]]
     (which expands to)  cats.data.EitherT[scala.concurrent.Future,Fail,scala.collection.immutable.Seq[Event]]
 Note: SubOfFail <: Fail, but class EitherT is invariant in type A.
 You may wish to define A as +A instead. (SLS 4.5)
     handler.execute(any[SubOfCommand]) returns SubOfFail().asLeftT[Future,
                                                                   ^
```

I understand the message about `EitherT` being invariant in type `A`. But I was expecting it to be able to translate `EitherT[F, SubOfA, B]` as `EitherT[F, SubOfA.asInstanceOf[A], B]`.

Can someone help me to reveal the flaw in my reasoning ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I was expecting it to be able to translate `EitherT[F, SubOfA, B]` as `EitherT[F, SubOfA.asInstanceOf[A], B]`.

Being invariant means exactly that it isn't possible to "translate" this way: an `EitherT[F, SubOfA, B]` simply isn't an `EitherT[F, A, B]`.

Now, a *separate* question is why the type for `fail` isn't inferred to be `Fail` despite an expected type for the whole `fail.asLeftT[Future, Seq[Receiver#E]]`. And the answer there is that Scala type inference just doesn't work that way; when typing `expression.method(...)`, it will type `expression` first and can't make use of the expected return type of `method`.

You can still write them inline, but you need type ascription:

```
(SubOfFail(): Fail).asLeftT[Future, Seq[Receiver#E]]
```

In case of `Seq`, explicit type parameter will work as well:

```
Seq[Event](SubOfEvent()).asRightT[Future, Fail]
```

Comment: I did not know that the expression was typed first, without considering the return type of the method. But it makes senses. Thanks for your quick answer.

Comment: Basically, without typing `expression` the compiler wouldn't know which `method` to use and what its signature is (or signatures if it's overloaded).